# Learning about 4 topics in physics

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian-formalism, noethers-theorem

This isn't really a question on any of those numerous underlying concepts behind the various sub-disciplines of physics, but hear me out:

I'm still in Higher Secondary, but I'd really love to know more about certain topics that would normally fall under a physicist's/mathematician's field of expertise, namely:

-**Lagrangian mechanics**

-**Hamiltonian mechanics**

-**Differential geometry**

-**Noether's Theorem**     [*especially this one*]

Unfortunately I'm clueless as to where I ought to begin reading up on these topics. I *did* try googling, but the day ended in a severe headache and the whole experience was of practically no help at all. Knowing that scores of people flock this site, I hope to tap into some of your expertise, hence I've posed this question.

Considering all of your experiences, I'd ***REALLY*** appreciate it if anyone could recommend any books, sites, articles, videos that'd help me grasp [with a fair degree of proficiency] the above-mentioned 4 topics.

I'd preferably like to have something convenient to refer to, that dwells more or less around the B.Sc physics level, and which I can tackle by myself [*largely*] without having to depend on someone else.
 [I'm almost done with Sear's and Zemansky's *University Physics* , if that provides any idea about the kind of material I wish to refer].

Request to Moderators: Please don't take down this 'question' just because it isn't the type of questions that are usually asked on this site. In fact if you can do anything to make this query more easily seen by more people at this community, it'd be welcome.
I don't have a mentor or teacher who'd be able to aid me in *those* particular topics.

Comment: Lagrangian/Hamiltonian: http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~simonm/mechanics.pdf

Comment: a course in mechanics https://homepages.dias.ie/ydri/Goldstein.pdf

Comment: Mit.edu/ocw in case you arent familiar.  Lots of video lectures and entire courses in physics.  Look for courses on mechanics for 1,2,and 4, and look for general relativity for item 3.

Comment: Differential geometry. Bernard Schutz

Comment: You really need to ask about this sort of thing [in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar). I've upvoted you to give you the 20 rep points needed to join the chat. The room is quiet at the moment, but then it's a Sunday. If you give it a few hours or wait until a weekday there are usually lots of people in the chat room.

Comment: I think Susskind's book  The Theoretical Minimum (https://www.amazon.com/Theoretical-Minimum-Start-Doing-Physics/dp/0465075681/ref=nosim/?tag=moseissase-20) is a very good place to start seeing the big picture.

Comment: There's also a sequel to The Theoretical Minimum...Quantum Mechanics: The Theoretical Minimum (https://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Mechanics-Theoretical-Leonard-Susskind/dp/0465062903)

Comment: Pardon my bluntness, but unlike others I am not inclined to indulge you.  Users of this site are expected to take reasonable steps to find an answer before posting here.  Your High School Physics teacher or textbooks (esp. Sears & Zemansky) will suggest suitable books for further study.  Failing that, there is the ubiquitous internet search.  Moreover, self-study requires initiative and motivation : if you are not able to find suitable study materials by yourself, I doubt that you can use them effectively.

Comment: @sammygerbil I'd have to disagree with that; I believe the OP is trying to get recommendations either a. from those who are in that field, so that the recommendations are better, or b. ones he hasn't seen before! He also is asking about topics that are not in the standard high school physics curriculum. Yes, the OP could Google it, but I'm guessing he has multiple times.

Comment: If you want a friendlier introduction to Lagrangian/Hamiltonian mechanics than Goldstein, Taylor's Classical Mechanics is very accessible.

Comment: @heather : Surely better to get recommendations from those who know your abilities than those who don't.  I see no evidence that the OP has done any research at all ("I'm clueless where to begin").  Not a good start for self-study.

Comment: @sammygerbil: Physics is a vast subject [undoubtedly you'd be knowing that by now], but Google is FAR larger.....I have, as a matter of fact, asked my teachers [of course I googled even before that] but they quite politely said they wouldn't be able to help me there, as its been a pretty long while since they last used these concepts. Of course Herr gerbil, you are right when you say I ought to ask those who are better aware of my abilities, but unfortunately they aren't of much help [though they do their best to help].  [Also do you normally play advocatus diaboli? ]

Comment: @user122066: Already checked some of those out earlier [on youtube], but thank you anyways. Also I don't think they're "entire courses",  just selected videos.....

Comment: I cant understand why there is such opposition to questions like these. ImHO it's fantastic that people come here looking to expand their education. We should applaud, indulge, and offer our expertises as it makes the world a much better place. Too often i see such discouraging and unhelpful comments and down votes as if it is a bad thing people are trying to learn or as if the commenters think theyre somehow superior to those asking questions like these....

Comment: @JohnRennie: Thanks! I'm relatively new to the site, but I'll be sure to make use of the chat room.....

Comment: @heather: I'd tick both options a. and b. ! Honestly glad you know how frustrating it is to pin down a good book, unlike a 'certain someone', I'm sure sammy meant well although as he mentioned, he did make his answer a  little "blunt"[I'd prefer the word 'harsh']....I'll be starting on that PDF you recommended. Thanks!

Comment: @annav: Goldstein's seems comprehensible [At least the first few pages are.....I'm still reading through it..] Thank you!

Comment: @WillO: The Theoretical minimum seems like a good book [that'd explain why you recommended it], the reviews are positive, but I'll have to try actually getting a hold of it and see how relevant it is to what I'm looking for......looks like I'll be paying a visit to the library again..... [P.S- If you know where I can get the PDF, it'd VERY helpful] Thank you!

Comment: @AaronAbraham, I'm in middle school and I love physics and am trying to learn as much as I can. I find I have the same problem (even more so because I've only had Algebra I, in terms of math) so I'm glad to help any way I can. Good luck! =)